# Working with Rails Timezones?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, time, timezone

Working on a 3 week new registration chart for metrics, I have the following code:

```
(3.weeks.ago.to_date..Date.today).map { |date| Metrics.registrations_on(date) }
```

In Metrics.rb:

```
def self.registrations_on(date)
  date = date.midnight
  end_date = date + 24.hours
  User.where(:created_at => date..end_date).count
end
```

Before the day is done here in California, a new day's numbers are already starting to increase. The `created_at` timestamp is UTC as well.

I'd like to be able to see the stats from today, using our time zone. With my data already saved as UTC I'm curious as to how about accomplishing this.

Comment: What is `config.time_zone` set as in your app?

Comment: It wasn't set, am I able to set it now and get the data I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `config/application.rb`, find `config.time_zone`, and assign it with appropriate value:

```
config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
```

Restart your app, and all ruby date/time operation should be adjusted automatically to your time zone.

For a list of all supported time zone strings, use:

```
bundle exec rake time:zones:all
```